# React-navigation StackNavigator render to specific screen

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

How can I render a Stack Navigator from [React-navigation](https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation) to a specific screen ?
Can I pass in a screen name as a prop to render the StackNavigator to that screen upon initial load?

**UPDATE:**
I solved it by passing in a prop to the Stack Navigator and then conditionally setting the intialRouteName:

```
const Main = RootNavigator(userLoggedIn);
```

then render the the Main like so `<Main />`
instead of the RootNavigator directly.

Then inside the Navigator code :

```
export const RootNavigator = (userLoggedIn= false) => {
  return StackNavigator(
    {
      LoggedIn: {
        screen: LoggedIn,
      },
      LoggedOut: {
        screen: LoggedOut,
      }
    },{
      initialRouteName: userLoggedIn? "LoggedIn" : "LoggedOut"
    }
  );
};
```

Comment: Check out the examples and docs https://reactnavigation.org

Comment: Not a helpful answer.

Comment: You need to add more detail about your code. Where is this being determined? What is receiving your prop/state? Are these different screens separate components? Are you using Redux or another state container? There are different ways to handle this so you [need to be more specific](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Why did you set userLoggedIn to false ?

Comment: I am implementing this same thing, but not able to pass LoginValue

Comment: That's new es6 feature that I used to set default value for userLoggedIn in case nothing gets passed in.

Comment: How you get the userLoggedIn value, I have used async storage to get the local state, but not able to pass that value in RootNavigator, values is undefined always

Comment: I'm using firebase to authenticate, initially user will be undefined since auth method are async. because of the nature of async userLoggedIn value is undefined initially. To solve that I set a default value for this as false. and when the firebase returns the value (true or false).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, when you initialise your `StackNavigator`, the second parameters is the options. So you can do :

```
StackNavigator({ <Your-Routes> }, { initialRouteName: 'MyFirstPage' });
```

Comment: I already know I can set the IntialRouteName within my StackNavigator but What I want to do is make that intialRoutename Dynamic, depending on some prop. i.e IF I'm logged In i want to show screenA in the Navigator and if i'm loggedOut show screenB